# Adding a request in two functions Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel

```js
public function saveHobbies(Request $request, $username){

        if (!$this->secure($username)) return redirect('/404');

        $my_hobbies = Auth::user()->hobbies()->get();

        $list = [];
        
        foreach($request->input('hobbies') as $i => $id){
            $list[$id] = 1;
        }
        
        foreach($my_hobbies as $hobby){
            $hobby_id = $hobby->hobby_id;
            if (!array_key_exists($hobby_id, $list)){
                $deleted = DB::delete('delete from user_hobbies where user_id='.Auth::id().' and hobby_id='.$hobby_id);
            }
            unset($list[$hobby_id]);
        }

        foreach($list as $id => $status){
            $hobby = new UserHobby();
            $hobby->user_id = Auth::id();
            $hobby->hobby_id = $id;
            $hobby->save();
        }

        $request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'Your hobbies have been successfully updated!');

        return redirect('/groups');    

    }
```

```html
 public function addGroup(Request $request){
        
        $user = Auth::user();

        $hobby = new Hobby;
        $hobby->name=$request->name;
        $hobby->save();

        $group = new Group;
        $group->hobby_id=$hobby->id;
        $group->save();

        $my_hobbies = new UserHobby;
        $my_hobbies->hobby_id=$hobby->id;
        $my_hobbies->user_id=$user->id;
        $my_hobbies = Auth::user()->$request->save();
        
        return redirect('/groups');

    }
```

Complete beginner, I have two functions, first is a function to create a new 'Hobby' (which are also group categories) and then the second function where user selects from those as their personal Hobbies(/groups)

This code was working fine until I tried to write some lines using $my_hobbies variable. The hobbies add to the DB and then the user can select from the DB. BUT! I added the $my_hobbies to add the Hobbies to the User selected hobbies automatically, without having to select the Hobby.

Meaning.. User creates/adds Hobby/group, it automatically appears in list of User hobbies. Where am I going wrong?? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling the save() function at the wrong place.
I am not sure what you want to do with: `$my_hobbies = Auth::user()->$request->save();`, if you simply save the object it should work.

```
 public function addGroup(Request $request){
        
        $user = Auth::user();

        $hobby = new Hobby;
        $hobby->name=$request->name;
        $hobby->save();

        $group = new Group;
        $group->hobby_id=$hobby->id;
        $group->save();

        $my_hobbies = new UserHobby;
        $my_hobbies->hobby_id=$hobby->id;
        $my_hobbies->user_id=$user->id;
        $my_hobbies->save();
        
        return redirect('/groups');

    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Lessons learned here. I was assuming I needed the request for some dumb reason.